Nodata to Zero values in promQL
Context:
I’m currently working on monitoring HAProxy logs using Loki and Prometheus. I’ve created a recording rule in Loki to count the logs:
Loki Query:
sum by (hostname, k8s_cluster_name) (count_over_time({hostname=~".*haproxy.*"} |= "" | json [5m]))
This query aggregates the log counts over 5-minute intervals, grouped by hostname and k8s_cluster_name.
Prometheus Query:
avg_over_time(haproxylogs{}[15m])
This PromQL query calculates the average number of HAProxy logs over a 15-minute window.
**Problem: **
I want to handle scenarios where logs are not received for a particular cluster/nodes, and these missing logs should be represented as zero/One values in Prometheus. I found the absent function in Prometheus, which converts “no data” to zero values. However, the absent function only works for single clusters, not across multiple clusters.

Try the following query:
0*last_over_time(haproxylogs[1d]) unless haproxylogs

This query should return haproxylogs time series with zero values if these time series were receiving samples during the last day (see 1d in square brackets), and stopped receiving samples now.
This query works in the following way:

it selects all samples for all the time series with the haproxylogs name over the last day
it obtains the last seen sample per each selected time series via the  last_over_time() function
it multiplies the the last seen sample per each time series by 0. This doesn't affect series' labels
it selects recently seen samples per each time series via haproxylogs series selector at the end of the query
it drops series with recently seen samples with the help of unless operator, leaving only series seen during the last day, but inactive right now.

Note that the query may consume a lot of CPU and RAM at Prometheus if the number of series with the haproxylogs name is too big or if the lookbehind window in square brackets at last_over_time() function is too big.
P.S. This query can be simplified to the following one when using MetricsQL - PromQL-like query language I work on:
0*(lag(haproxylogs[1d]) > 5m)

This query compares the results returned by lag() function with 5m, so it returns haproxylogs time series seen during the last day, which were inactive for more than 5 minutes.
